# What is the limit of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can you show te steps to compte such limit ,thanks

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$  $2^\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: Don't you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ perhaps?

Comment: Do you know $f(x)=2^x$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $2^{-1/n}\le2^{(-1)^n/n}\le2^{1/n}$, and squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use $$-\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$$ and the continuity of the exponential function.

Comment: thankss the $(-1)^n$ just ruins everything :p